# TFS: Updating iteration path using python TFSAPI

Tags: python, tfs

I have a problem updating the iteration path for a TFS workitem using TFSAPI.
I'm using python TFSAPI from [here](https://devopshq.github.io/tfs/).
I have no problem reading the workitem iteration path and I have no problem updating other fields. 
When updating iteration path using any value, I get an exception 'HTTP 400 bad request'.

I tried the following:

```
workitem['IterationPath'] = <some valid iteration path value>
workitem['IterarionId'] = <some other validiteration id>
workitem['IterationLevel3'] = <some valid level 3 value>
```

Comment: What is the specific error message? There are many reasons for `HTTP 400 bad request`, we need specific information to know the cause of your error. BTW, If you use PAT for authentication, please confirm that your PAT has read and write permissions.

Comment: I can't find a way to log any specific error message. I'm not using PAT authentication. I'm using HttpNegotiateAuth library.
I don't have write permission issues since I am able to update any other field but this.